# How to override WebSocket send() method

Tags: javascript, websocket, overriding

I'm trying to override the `WebSocket.send()` method.
My objective is being able to fuzz the sent data to test robustness of the server implementation.

I'm adopting this approach:

```
// OVERRIDE WEBSOCKET SEND METHOD
WebSocket.prototype.oldSend = WebSocket.prototype.send;

WebSocket.prototype.send = function(data) {
     console.log("ws: sending data");
     WebSocket.prototype.oldSend(data);
};
```

This fails when the `WebSocket.prototype.oldSend(data)` command is called the first time, with the error:
    Failed to send: 'send' called on an object that does not implement interface WebSocket.

Anybody if it is possible to override the built-in websocket send method(), or what else I'm missing?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
WebSocket.prototype.oldSend = WebSocket.prototype.send;

WebSocket.prototype.send = function(data) {
     console.log("ws: sending data");
     WebSocket.prototype.oldSend.apply(this, [data]);
};
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrrh0znu/)

Comment: This seems to work. Can also you explain why? My guess is that when you call `this.send()` the interpreter will look for the method in the prototype anyway. Thanks.

Comment: `WebSocket.prototype.send` will not work because this invocation is not calling the `send` method in the scope of the socket element but rather in the scope of it's prototype object (which is not the same as you can probably tell from the error message). Instead if you try `WebSocket.prototype.oldSend.apply(this, arguments)` which will also pass the correct scope to the method, it ought to work the way you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't override WebSocket.send() implementation, as it is read-only in most of browser.

All you can do is something like:

```
var mysend = function(data) {
    console.log("ws: sending data");
    WebSocket.send(data);
};
```

which should do the trick anyway, without messing with prototypes.