# Modifying websocket wss send message before it is sent

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, reverse-engineering, puppeteer, wss

I am curious if it is possible to modify a wss send message before it is sent. For example, if I know the second send message is always the same, can I modify it to say something else? And how would I go about doing it (can it be done with puppeteer)? If not, is it possible to instead look for a string in the send messages before it is sent and change it so something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override WebSocket send() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341197/how-to-override-websocket-send-method)