# How to override WebSocket onmessage Event

Tags: javascript, websocket

One application uses websocket onmessage() event to parse websocket response messages. I want to see in real time, the websocket response data received the application in console.

So I want to override websocket "message" method /onmessage event in following manner.

[How to override WebSocket send() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341197/how-to-override-websocket-send-method)

The "send" overriding works , however "message" doesn't work.

```
WebSocket.prototype.oldmessage = WebSocket.prototype.message;
WebSocket.prototype.message = function(data) {
     console.log("ws: received data " + data);
     WebSocket.prototype.oldmessage.apply(this, [data]);
};
```

And also this doesn't work

```
if (WebSocket.prototype.onmessage) {
    (function() {
         var old_handler = WebSocket.prototype.onmessage;
         WebSocket.prototype.onmessage = function() {
            console.log('hii')
            old_handler.apply(this, arguments);
         };
    }());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you see onmessage is a property with get and set method where as send is just a method which you can override, seems like there is no easy way to override getters and setters, one more things to consider here is Websocket.prototype is not extensible you can not add new properties to the prototype (you can update though).
you can do something like this

```
window.onmessagegetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(WebSocket.prototype, 'onmessage').get;
window.onmessagesetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(WebSocket.prototype, 'onmessage').set;
Object.defineProperty(window.WebSocket.prototype, 'onmessage', {
  get() {
    logger.log('getCalled');
    return window.onmessagegetter.apply(this);
  },
  set() {
    logger.log('setCalled');
    return window.onmessagesetter.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```